# Creating a ajava script array in given format with carousel?

Tags: javascript

Creating a ajava script array in given format with carousel ?

Iam  using carousel.js & carousel.css, its working fine with static data, but when im trying to put dynamic data its hot happening. Im not able to create the value array in given format.

```
   <script>
                  var carousel2 = new widgets.Carousel( {

                        uuid : "carousel2",
                        widgetDir : "carousel/",
                        args : { "theme" : "gray", "scrollCarousel" : true, },
                        value : [


                           { 
                             "image" : "images/banner/big_banner_01.jpg",

                           },

                           { 
                             "image" : "images/banner/big_banner_02.jpg",

                           },

                           {
                             "image" : "images/banner/big_banner_03.jpg",

                             },

                           { 
                              "image" : "images/banner/big_banner_04.jpg",

                           },

                           { 
                              "image" : "images/banner/big_banner_05.jpg",

                           }
                        ]
                      } );
                </script>


      I need to pass the value for "value" key dynamically.  How can i form this dynamically .IM TRYING WITH THE BELOW ONE

        <repeat index="index.value" ref="DATA">
        <repeat ref="VAL">
            <choose ref="LANGUAGE">
                <when value="${lang}">hiii
                    <script>
                    val[index.value] = "{"+"'image' :" +${IMAGE}+"}";</script>
                </when>
                <otherwise/>
            </choose>
        </repeat>
    </repeat>


    This is not working.
```

Comment: Above the carousel2 variable - set up an object which contains the value data. You can use javascript to loop through your html to recover the order of the images and their urls - forming an object. You can then pass this object through to the carousel widget code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var generateCaroseul = {

            getData: function(){

                //loop through html to create an object with the data.
                var dataObj = null;
                $('li').each(function(index) {
                    var imgUrl = $(this).attr("src");
                    dataObj.add("image", imgUrl);
                });

                return dataObj;
            }
  };


  var carousel2 = new widgets.Carousel( {

        uuid : "carousel2",
        widgetDir : "carousel/",
        args : { "theme" : "gray", "scrollCarousel" : true, },
        value : generateCaroseul.getData()
      } );
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry man, its not tested code - you are probably now accessing the variable in scope - but the dataObj.add is probably wrong - try setting the dataObj to something and see if its getting a value now